# Why the area of a circle is not equal to $\frac{(r^2\pi^2)}{4}$?

Tags: geometry

I understand the logic behind the area of a circle been equal to $r^2\pi$, but I can't figure out why the perimeter of a circle couldn't be split into four approximately equal parts and then squared to give the same area. I suppose it have something to do with pi having a infinite decimal representation.

Many Thanks,

Jhonny

Comment: Pi being infinite?

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_circle

Comment: Your formula is correct, provided you adjust with the factor $\approx 1.273239544735$ to take curvature into account.

Comment: Why don't you divide the perimeter into **three** equal parts and use the formula for the area of an equilateral triangle?

Comment: @Professor Vector I think, there is a word "disc".

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg So do I, but I can't see a connection to my comment, sorry.

Comment: @Professor Vector Your comment has no any relation with starting problem. We need to understand why $\frac{\pi^2r^2}{4}\neq0$. About which perimeter do you say?

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg "Perimeter" was a quote from the original post, you might try rereading it. What I need to understand, I decide myself. I'm sorry I can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Same perimeter of two figures  doesn't mean the area enclosed by them is equal.

So you cannot cut a circle into four pieces of length $\pi r/2$ and get an area of $\pi^2 r^2/4$

If we follow you reasoning, we can cut the circle into four pieces with two of them having $\text{length}\rightarrow\pi r$ and other two having $\text{length}\rightarrow 0$ and arrange them to form a rectangle having $\text{area}\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Spot on. Many Thanks